# How to check first proxy and start connection and terminate if successful?

Tags: python

I want to use proxy lists but I'm not sure how to do this:

Check if first connection is established (it does not matter it is the first proxy IP or not), run something and then close the program and exit, else go to the next proxy.

This is my code that loops over all proxies:

```
import requests
from Proxy_List_Scrapper import Scrapper, Proxy, ScrapperException
ALL = 'ALL'
scrapper = Scrapper(category=ALL, print_err_trace=False)
# Get ALL Proxies According to your Choice
data = scrapper.getProxies()
n = 0
while True:
    n += 1
    try:
        for item in data.proxies:
            # Enter a proxy IP address and port.
            url = 'http://api.ipify.org'

            # Send a GET request to the url and pass the proxy as a parameter.
            page = requests.get(url, proxies={"http": f'{item.ip}:{item.port}', "https": f'{item.ip}:{item.port}'})

            # Prints the content of the requested url.
            print(f'proxy is {item.ip}:{item.port} and content is {page.text}')
    except requests.exceptions.ProxyError:
        print(f'error #{n}')
```

Comment: maybe you should run `try/except inside `for`-loop (not outside `for`-loop)` and use `break` before `except` to exit `for`-loop when you finish task. And when there will be problem then try/except will catch it and it will run code for next value `for item in data.proxies;`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should run `try/except` inside `for`-loop - to catch problem with proxy server and continue with next proxy on list. And you could use `break` to finish loop when you find working proxy.

Something like this:

```
import requests
from Proxy_List_Scrapper import Scrapper, Proxy, ScrapperException

scrapper = Scrapper(category='ALL', print_err_trace=False)
data = scrapper.getProxies()

url = 'http://api.ipify.org'

for n, item in enumerate(data.proxies):
    try:
        page = requests.get(url, proxies={"http": f'{item.ip}:{item.port}', "https": f'{item.ip}:{item.port}'})

        print(f'proxy is {item.ip}:{item.port} and content is {page.text}')
        
        # exit `for`-loop when connection finished without error and it gives different IP
        if page.text != my_original_ip:
            break  
    except requests.exceptions.ProxyError:
        print(f'error #{n}  {item.ip}:{item.port}')
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to declare `my_original_ip`?

Comment: open page `http://api.ipify.org`without proxy and copy result

Comment: Yes, but it's going to check if my IP equals with the proxy IP, then `break` the loop and exit. Suppose I don't know which proxy works (there are around 1K).

Comment: If you first open in browser http://api.ipify.org **without proxy** then you get you real IP, not proxy IP. And later in code you check `your_real_IP != IP_from_page` and if proxy works correctly then `IP_from_page` should be different (it doesn't matter it is proxy IP). If proxy sends your IP to server then it should give your original IP. And if proxy totally doesn't work then it should rather crash connection (or block connections and it may need to set `timeout` in `requests`.